# Size of a request header field exceeds server limit

Tags: apache-2.2

Here's an interesting case of a client getting the a "400 Bad Request" error and seemingly unable to view a drupal home page hosted on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS using Apache/2.2.22:

> **Bad Request**
>   Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. 
>   Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.

Packet sniffing output:

```
...
T 2013/09/02 15:23:10.458167 ###.###.###.###:40027 -> ###.###.###.###:80 [A]
GET / HTTP/1.0.
If-None-Match: "1363160742-0", "1363165573-1", "1363175854-1", "1363175854-0", "1363179616-0", "1363181811-0", "1363239319-1", "1363255903-0", "1363259282-0", "1363263398-1", "1363274564-0", "1363329642-0", "1363332613-1", "1363333851-0", "1363599826-0", "1363678909-0", "1363684227-1", "1363699732-0", "1363755181-0", "1363765691-1", "1363767178-0", "1363780208-0", "1363787589-0", "1363795259-1", "1363852409-1", "1363863225-1", "1363928115-0", "1363951793-0", "1363951793-1", "1364133610-1", "1364187608-1", "1364187608-0", "1364203083-0", "1364208174-0", "1364214930-0", "1364219815-0", "1364274441-1", "1364280930-0", "1364280930-1", "1364286055-1", "1364298840-0", "1364298840-1", "1364360674-0", "1364364356-1", "1364381508-0", "1364385520-1", "1364460734-0", "1364882595-1", "1364903271-0", "1364967946-0", "1364967946-1", "1364981713-0", "1364985142-1", "1364992835-1", "1365061578-0", "1365065290-1", "1365076128-0", "1365141088-1", "1365167701-0", "1365171024-0", "1365402404-1", "1365402404-0", "1365411731-1", "1365416882-0", "1365476715-0", "1365487578-0", "1365488880-1", "1365503922-1", "1365514224-1", "1365579101-0", "1365580320-0", "1365582817-0", "1365584926-0", "1365589524-0", "1365608307-0", "1365649987-0", "1365682295-0", "1365685083-0", "1365770532-1", "1365770532-0", "1365844566-0", "1365996619-1", "1366093719-1", "1366093719-0", "1366115408-0", "1366180275-1", "1366186431-0", "1366196476-0", "13662669
...
```

At this stage I am not 100% sure whether it is just limited to a specific client but the error was reported by a user with the following user agent string:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/534.57.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.7
```

Now the question remains what to do, is it a server issue or just a misbehaving client?

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be an issue with the user's proxy server keeping too many variants of the cached page ([old versions of squid would do this](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/201204/0534.html), for instance). Have them upgrade or remove the proxy server, clear their browser cache, and try again.

It could also be *your* caching reverse proxy, if you are running one.

Comment: A temporary workaround was to increase `LimitRequestFieldSize` in the Apache configuration as answered on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340792/size-of-a-request-header-field-exceeds-server-limit-due-to-many-if-none-match-va/340795) but your answer seems to me more like the real cause of the issue.